How to Sell GM Token on GMX for USDC Only (No Volatile Tokens) on Arbitrum?
I'm currently holding some GM tokens on the Arbitrum chain and I'd like to sell them directly for USDC, without receiving any other volatile tokens. My goal is to avoid any exposure to market volatility and swap GM tokens exclusively for USDC.
What is the process to do the following via directly interacting with the smart contract?
Thank you!
